# Delete na columns through several dataframe

Tags: r

I would like to delete columns full of na values in several data frame
I tried to use a function and loop through a list of dataframes but it doesn't work properly

I would like to obtain as output each dataframe in the list without na columns

Comment: The used script : drop_empty_cols_for_loop <- function(df) {
  for (nm in names(df))
    if(all(is.na(df[[nm]])))
      df[[nm]] <- NULL
  df
}        data_frame_list<-paste0('df_',unique(df3$DATE))                         for (i in data_frame_list){i<-drop_empty_cols_for_loop(i)}

Comment: When you say delete NA columns.  Is it any NA element in column, then delete the column or is it full of `NA`s and then delete

Comment: The columns  are full of na and I would like to delete them

Comment: You should add this details to the question, not in the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can place the datasets in a `list` and then remove it

```
lst1 <- lapply(lst, function(dat) Filter(function(x) !all(is.na(x)), dat))
lst1
#[[1]]
#  col2 col3
#1   NA   12
#2   24   22

#[[2]]
#  col2 col3
#1   NA   12
#2   24   22
```

---

In the OP's code,

```
data_frame_list <- paste0('df_',unique(df3$DATE))
```

is just a string, we can get the values with `mget`

```
lst2 <- mget(paste0('df_',unique(df3$DATE)))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = NA, col2 = c(NA, 24), col3 = c(12, 22))
df2 <- df1
lst <- mget(paste0("df", 1:2))
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It seems that it is my dataframe list the problem I use the Following script to get the list : data_frame_list<list(paste0('df_',unique(df3$DATE)))

Comment: @dam  I showed a reproducible example and it is working for me

Comment: @dam You need `mget` `lst <- mget(paste0('df_',unique(df3$DATE)))`

Comment: I get an error : Error: valeur pour ‘df_cx’ introuvable

Comment: yes, sorry , value 'df_cx' not found. When I delete the mget function it works

Comment: @dam is it working or not working?  Here,  it assumes that you already created the `df_cx` object.  If it is not there, it wouldn't be found.  If you look at my example, I created the objects 'df1', 'df2' and then I am calling `mget`

Comment: @dam `not working`  is not clear.  But, as I said, if the objects are already created it should work fine as I have already showed

Comment: My data frame list contains :  data_frame_list
[1] "df_201903" "df_201905".When I use the script i obtain :lst <- mget(paste0('df_',unique(df3$DATE)))
Error: valeur pour ‘df_201903’ introuvable
> lst <- mget(data_frame_list)
Error: valeur pour ‘df_201903’ introuvable

Comment: @dam when you do `mget(data_frame_list)` and if the object is not already created, it returns the error.  the error is because you didn't create the object.  Please type `df_201903` in the console.  I think that object is not present

Comment: No, unfortunaly : data_frame_list<-paste0('df_',unique(df3$DATE))
> lst <- mget(data_frame_list)
Error: valeur pour ‘df_201903’ introuvable

Comment: @dam Please check `df_201903` by typing on the console.  I think that object is not yet created

Comment: I launched a new r session and the complete job including your script. It works properly. Thank very much!